# query is super slow with like and order by

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a following query:

```
SELECT  k from 
tbl t
WHERE 
(LOWER( col1 ) LIKE '9000000003%')
AND 
(col2=12334534 )
order by  t.col1  ASC
LIMIT 0,50
```

`tbl` has about 187000 rows

this query is very slow (I could not wait till it finishes) when I have like in `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` together. But if I remove `ORDER BY` or `LIKE` condition query runs in feasible time

This query also executes pretty fast when I split it into two queries:

```
SELECT k from (
select * from 
tbl t
WHERE 
(LOWER( col1 ) LIKE '9000000003%')
AND 
(col2=12334534 )
) x
order by x.col1  ASC
LIMIT 0,50
```

Main problem is that query is generated, so I can not rewrite it.

How can I optimize it?

**Explain plan**

```
id   select_type  table   type   possible_keys    key       key_len   ref  rows   extra
'1', 'SIMPLE',    'tbl', 'index',     NULL,     'col1_idx', '768',    NULL, '50', 'Using where'
```

**DDL**

```
field  type         null    key   default extra
k      bigint(20)   NO      PRI     
col1   varchar(255) YES     MUL     
col2   bigint(20)   NO
```

PS I have full access to mysql server (I use 5.6)

Comment: Assuming col1 is indexed on the table. Wondering if LOWER has anything to do with the query and what happens if you remove it. Could you provide EXPLAIN?

Comment: Provide DDLs and an EXPLAIN

Comment: @Strawberry, added ddl and explain plan

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT k
from  tbl t
WHERE LOWER( col1 ) LIKE '9000000003%' AND 
      col2 = 12334534
order by t.col1 ASC
LIMIT 0, 50;
```

The `lower()` is totally unnecessary because the pattern has only numbers (plus the default collation is case insensitive for `like`).  So, you can rewrite the query like this:

```
SELECT k
from  tbl t
WHERE col1 LIKE '9000000003%' AND 
      col2 = 12334534
order by t.col1 ASC
LIMIT 0, 50;
```

Then, you can use an index to speed the query.  The best index is:

```
create index tbl_col2_col1_k on tbl(col2, col1, k);
```

This should make the query blazingly fast.

Comment: `So, you can rewrite the query like this:` I can not rewrite query

Comment: What do you mean you cannot rewrite the query?  Your question has two versions of it.

Comment: yep, but rewritten query I can only execute manually. This query is generated by an ORM and that query I can not rewrite.

Comment: @michaelnesterenko . . . Try it with the index anyway, you might get lucky.  You should fix the ORM so it doesn't write bad queries, or find another tool if you care about performance.

Comment: Removing `lower` from `like` condition speedups query a lot. If only `mysql` had function-based indexes...

Comment: ORM's help developer performance. They do not help runtime performance.